# Python: Remove a portion of a string from a list of strings

Tags: python, xlrd

I used xlrd to extract a column from an excel sheet to make into a list.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
book = xlrd.open_workbook("HEENT.xlsx").sheet_by_index(0)
med_name = []
for row in sheet.col(2):
    med_name.append(row)
med_school = []
for row in sheet.col(3):
    med_school.append(row)
print(med_school)
```

Below is a snippet of the list: med_school.

```
[text:'University of San Francisco', 
text: 'Harvard University', 
text:'Class of 2016, University of Maryland School of Medicine', 
text:'Class of 2015, Johns Hopkins University School of Medicine', 
text:'Class of 2014, Raymond and Ruth Perelman School of Medicine at the
University of Pennsylvania']
```

I want to remove "text:'Class of 2014" from each string in the list. I tried list comprehension, but I got an attribute error: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'strip'. Does anyone know of a way to create a list of medical school names that have just the medical school names without the class year and the word "text"?

Comment: Something is wrong with that example list output. Perhaps there are meant to be extra quotes, like `"text: 'Class of ...'"`?  Perhaps copy/paste *directly* from your output to here, if you haven't already.

Comment: Are you sure there are no double-quotes before **text:** and at the end of each row?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the list output, this is simply the way an `xlrd.Cell` instance implements `__repr__`

Comment: Thank you @donkopotamus for the clarification. Yes, I copied and pasted the list outputs.

Comment: Can you please update the problem description to be complete and accurate?  Missing quotation marks, removing only 2014, assuming the "Class of" string exists ... each of these has brought you feedback that doesn't solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 4):

The `xlrd` does not return you strings, it returns you instances of a class called `Cell`.  This has a property `value` that contains the string you are seeing.

To modify these simply:

```
for cell in med_school:
    cell.value = cell.value[:15]
```

This will remove the first 15 characters ("Class of 2014, ").  Alternatively you could use other approaches like string splitting (on ",") or a regex.

The point here is that you shouldn't be working directly on the values in the `med_schools` list, but on their `.value` property. Or extract it to somewhere else you could work on it.

For example, to get all of the text properties, dropping the prefix:

```
values = [cell.value[15:] for cell in med_schools]
```

Or using a regex to replace to replace only those actualling containing the offending data

```
values = [re.sub(r"^Class of \d{4}, ", "", cell.value) for cell in med_schools]
```

Comment: I tried the first two solutions, and I got an attribute error: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Alter `.text` to `.value`

Comment: thank you so much! My code worked. Do you have the link to this documentation? Some of my values don't have "Class of 201", so I am looking for the syntax of how to do an if statement that only removes the first 15 characters when the value has "Class of 201".

Answer (score 1):

Use the given separator to cut off the head of each string.  Check first to make sure it has "Class", so we know the comma-space is there.

```
med_school = ["text:'Class of 2016, University of Maryland School of Medicine'",  
              "text:'Class of 2015, Johns Hopkins University School of Medicine'", 
              "text:'Class of 2014, Raymond and Ruth Perelman School of Medicine at the University of Pennsylvania'",
              "text:'Class of 1989, Rush Medical School / Knox College'",
              "text:'Bernie\'s Back-Alley School of Black-Market Techniques'"
             ]

school_name = []
for first in med_school:
    name = first.value
    if ", " in name:
        cut  = name.index(", ")
        name = name[cut+2:]
    else:
        name = name[6:-1]
    school_name.append(name)

print school_name
```

output (with extra line feeds to improve readability):

```
["University of Maryland School of Medicine'",
 "Johns Hopkins University School of Medicine'",
 "Raymond and Ruth Perelman School of Medicine at the University of Pennsylvania'"
 "Rush Medical School / Knox College'", 
 "Bernie's Back-Alley School of Black-Market Techniques"]
```

You could also wrap the loop into a list comprehension:

```
school_name = [name.value[name.value.index(", ")+2:] \
                       if ", " in name \
                       else name[6:-1]   \
                   for name in med_school]
```

Comment: I also tried this solution, and I got an attribute error:  'Cell' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: I tried both solutions, and I encountered a value error that says "substring not found". The error occurs in the line with "name.value.index(", "))

Comment: That's what happens if **name.value** doesn't have a comma-space.  Are there any such records?

Comment: Some of the cells don't have "Class of 201" and the comma. I only want to remove those characters from cells that do have "Class".

Comment: Then I suspect that the code @donkopotamus gave you also doesn't solve *your* problem ... which you still haven't entirely described.

Comment: If they don't have "Class of 201?, " ... then what *do* they have?

Comment: I've upgraded my answer for a couple of extra possibilities.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the string in my code above. If they don't have "Class of 201", it's just the school name, which is what I want to retain.

Comment: In that case, I think the code I gave you should do the job.  If not, it will be quite close.  I don't have your xlrd package to test on here.

Answer (score 1):

Change `for row in sheet.col(2)` to `for row in sheet.col(2).value`.
U will get rid of the do file type and get the actual value.
Do this.

`results =[]`

`for row in sheet.col(2).value:
                print(row)`